# How to make a CDF?

Tags: cdf-format, interactive, cdfplayer

I am using Mathematica 12 on Mac.

I would like to export the following code to a CDF file.

```
  g1[a_] := ParametricPlot3D[{a*Cos[\[Theta]]*Sin[\[Phi]], 
    a*Sin[\[Theta]]*Sin[\[Phi]], a*Cos[\[Phi]]}, {\[Theta], 0, 
    2 \[Pi]}, {\[Phi], \[Pi]/2, \[Pi]}, Mesh -> 50, 
   MeshStyle -> Opacity[.2], 
   PlotStyle -> {Directive[{Green, Opacity[0.15], Thickness[.005]}]}];

  level = 0;



 p4 = Graphics3D[{Polygon[{{-2.2, -2.2, level}, {-2.2, 2.2, 
           level}, {2.2, 2.2, level}, {2.2, -2.2, level}}]}, 
       Opacity[0.05], Lighting -> "Neutral"];

 shh1 = Manipulate[Show[g1[a], p4], {{a, 1}, 1, 5, 1/50}];
```

I searched around and found this command:

```
CDFDeploy["happy.cdf", shh1]
```

But the output (the happy.cdf) is only a static pictute, without interactive manipulation.

Could anyone help me with a hint?

Comment: `without interactive manipulation` how do you expect this interaction to show up? By itself? You have not done any  interactive manipulation in the code you are exporting. You just exported a static image so naturally the CDF will contain a static image.

Comment: @Nasser I meant that at least we can rotate the image as normal. Did I get a wrong understanding here? So we need to have some manipulation so that the CDF makes sense?

Comment: My understanding is that CDF is meant to work only  with `Dynamic` content. Something like `Dynamic` module or `Manipulate`. 

Rotating that content you saved using mouse and such does not work on its own, either if you open the CDF file using the CDF Player or open the CDF file using Mathematica itself. The content needs to be Dynamic for any interaction.

Comment: @Nasser Hi, Thanks, now I 've modified the code so that we have the function Manipulate. I did try CDFDeploy["happy.cdf", shh1] but it did not work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> now I 've modified the code so that we have the function Manipulate. I
>   did try CDFDeploy["happy.cdf", shh1] but it did not work

This is because the Manipulate you saved did not contain all the functions it needed to run. You need to have everything it needs inside it. One option is to use the `Initialization` section of Manipulate, or to use `SaveDefinitions`. I prefer `Initialization` myself.

```
shh1 = Manipulate[
   Show[g1[a], p4],
   {{a, 1}, 1, 5, 1/50},
   Initialization :> (
     g1[a_] := 
      ParametricPlot3D[{a*Cos[\[Theta]]*Sin[\[Phi]], 
        a*Sin[\[Theta]]*Sin[\[Phi]], a*Cos[\[Phi]]}, {\[Theta], 0, 
        2 \[Pi]}, {\[Phi], \[Pi]/2, \[Pi]}, Mesh -> 50, 
       MeshStyle -> Opacity[.2], 
       PlotStyle -> {Directive[{Green, Opacity[0.15], 
           Thickness[.005]}]}];
     level = 0;
     p4 = 
      Graphics3D[{Polygon[{{-2.2, -2.2, level}, {-2.2, 2.2, 
           level}, {2.2, 2.2, level}, {2.2, -2.2, level}}]}, 
       Opacity[0.05], Lighting -> "Neutral"]
     )
   ];

    CDFDeploy["happy.cdf", shh1]
```

Now it works inside CDF player OK

[image]

Comment: It's very knowledgeable. Could you give me one more favor, how could you create the gif. file with your mouse in action like this?

Comment: @Binjiu I use screen capture software which saves it to animated GIF file. it is free. It is called LICcap (if you google it you find it). Easy to use also.

Comment: Thank so much. I will try it now.